# Deserialization a file to remove a object and then do Serialization again

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to do Deserialization of a file "series.dat" to remove a object in it. My aproach is first to the Deserialization and then add each object to an array, then remove that position of the array that contains the object I want to remove. Then when I am finished to the Seralization again.

The problem is, it only reads one object, when in fact there is 3 of them.

````
    public static void EliminarLs(int posicion) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        try{
   
            List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();
            
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("series.dat");

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

try {
  
 
    while (true) {
        results.add(ois.readObject());
    }
    
  
} catch (OptionalDataException e) {
    if (!e.eof) 
        throw e;
} finally {
    System.out.println(results.size());
    results.remove(posicion);
    ois.close();
}



fis.close();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    ```
    The error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 1

Any idead why? Or a better way to do so.
Thanks in advance!
````

Answer (score 0):

This is not deserialization, but I'm not going to go into that. What you're doing is only reading a file line by line, adding the lines to an array and then removing a specific line as seen here:

```
results.remove(posicion);
```

There is nothing that indicates that you are looking for any specific content, it just removes the Nth element in the array based on what argument you put in

```
public static void EliminarLs(int posicion)
```

The reason why you're getting the error is that you're trying to remove an element on a position outside of the array, in your case you're trying to remove the 4th line from a 1-line file.